# Getting redirected on new action for controller Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I'm having trouble with the new and show actions for my events controller. Currently, I can only access the index where the events are listed. But, I get 302 redirected when I try to create new events and even show the current_users events. Can you help me fix this issue to allow the current_biz_user to see his or her created events while also allowing them to post new events to the index for public viewership? Thank you.

Here are my routes as well.

```
events GET    /events(.:format)                            events#index
                          POST   /events(.:format)                            events#create
                new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)                        events#new
                    event GET    /events/:id(.:format)                        events#show
                          PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)                        events#update
                          PUT    /events/:id(.:format)                        events#update



class EventsController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :set_search
      before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :update, :create, :new]
      respond_to :html, :json

      def index
        @events = Event.all.order("created_at DESC")
        @search = Event.search(params[:q])
        @events = @search.result
        @search.build_condition if @search.conditions.empty?
        @search.build_sort if @search.sorts.empty?
        respond_with(@events)
      end

      def show
        @event = Event.friendly.find(params[:id])
        @eventcreator = BizUser.find(@event.biz_user_id)
        respond_with(@event)
      end

      def new
        @event = Event.new
      end

      def edit
        @event = Event.find(params[:id])
      end

      def create
        @event = Event.new(event_params)
        @event.biz_user = current_user

        respond_to do |format|
          if @event.save
            format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @event.update(event_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @event }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      private
        def set_event
          @event = Event.find(params[:id])

        end

        def set_search
          @q = Event.search(params[:q])
        end

        def event_params
          params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description, :city, :state, :from_time, :to_time, :date, :eventlogo, :manager, :managerdescription, :reservation, :eventtype, :theme, :capacity, :passname, :private, :alcohol, :ticketquantity, :options, :price, :category, :biz_user_id)
        end
    end
```

Comment: Could you show your `update` and `create` methods as well? What exactly are you doing, that doesn't give the expected result? I don't think this is the problem you're asking about, but in your `index` method, line 3 overwrites your @events variable, so you might as well delete the first line that sets @events. Or if you need both, use different variable names.

Comment: I changed line 3 from events to findevents = @search.result. Currently, I'm using ransack gem to provide the search engine mechanism. It's blocking me from creating new actions and also accessing the events/index page. In other words, I can only search for events, but I can't reach the index page for the events w/o providing anything to the search query. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
 before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :update, :create, :new]
```

To this:

```
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :update]
```

Also, review your before_actions. I don't think you need set_search applied on all your controller actions

Comment: I set before_filter :set_search, except: [:new, :create, :edit, :update] and ransack is still giving me issues when I try to create a new event.

Comment: Without the before_filter :set_search action. The ransack search engine only works on one controller. Since, it's embedded into my navbar, I had to use the filter inside of the application_controller.